# issue in showing pager after reloading the jqxgrid data on click event

Tags: jqxgrid

I am trying to reload the grid on click event. Here is my code for grid

```
var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [                     
                        { name: 'sno' },
                        { name: 'bid' },
                        { name: 'city' },                    
                        { name: 'booking_date' },                    
                        { name: 'amount' },                  
                        { name: 'customer_contact' },                    
                        { name: 'user_name' },                   
                        { name: 'trip_type' },
                        { name: 'comments' },
                        { name: 'action' },
            ],
            cache: false,
            url: 'order_details.php?flag=2&start_date='+start_date_param+'&end_date='+end_date_param,              
            data: {
                pagesize:50
            },
            root: 'Rows',
            //sortcolumn: 'area',
           // sortdirection: 'asc',
           beforeprocessing: function (data) {
                source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;
            }
        };
        dataadapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

        // initialize jqxGrid
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 1100,
            source: dataadapter,
            theme: 'classic',
            autoheight: true,
            pageable: true,
            pagesize:50,
            enablebrowserselection: true, 
            selectionmode: 'singlecell',
            //sortable:true,
            virtualmode: true,
            rendergridrows: function (params) {
                return params.data;
            },
            columns:
            [   
                { text: 'No', datafield: 'sno', width: 30 },
                { text: 'Booking Id', datafield: 'bid', width: 90, align: 'center',cellsAlign: 'center' },
                { text: 'City', datafield: 'city', width: 170 },
                { text: 'Car Book Date', datafield: 'booking_date', width: 100, align: 'center',cellsAlign: 'center' },
                { text: 'Amount', datafield: 'amount', width: 60, align: 'right',cellsAlign: 'right' },
                { text: 'Customer Contact', datafield: 'customer_contact', width: 205 },
                { text: 'User Name', datafield: 'user_name', width: 125 },
                { text: 'Trip Type', datafield: 'trip_type', width: 160},
                { text: 'Comments', datafield: 'comments', width: 80, align: 'center',cellsAlign: 'center'},
                { text: 'Action', datafield: 'action', width: 80, align: 'center',cellsAlign: 'center'},
            ]
        });

        // event handling on select of date range and click on button show 
        $("#btn_show").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var start_date_param = $("#start_date").val();
            var end_date_param = $("#end_date").val();
            source.url = 'order_details.php?flag=2&start_date='+start_date_param+'&end_date='+end_date_param; 
              dataadapter.dataBind();
        });
```

On click of button "btn_show", I could get the data from page 0, but if I am on page 4, then after click event, my grid pager is remains on page 4 only and data is display for page 0.If I click on next page, then it jumps from page 0 to next page i.e page 5.
   Why jqxgrid is not resetting its recordedstartindex and recordedendindex values on dataadapter.dataBind() call after click event?
Do I need to use any other function to reload my complete grid??

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following:

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('gotopage', 0);
```

should replace

```
dataadapter.dataBind();
```

In your code.

Comment: Its just going to page0, but I want to reload the new grid content, which is not happening after click event. Need to use something else

Comment: gotopage goes to page 0 and performs "updatebounddata". I suggest you to implement the adapter's formatData callback and put your custom parameters there and gotopage call will be enough.